# Can't get record from DB by created_at field

Tags: php, sql, datetime, laravel-4, eloquent

I need to get data from DB with 'created_at' field for last 14 days. I'm using laravel 4.

when i'm selecting like this

```
$someDate = '2014-07-10'; // for example <br/>
$records = Records::where('created_at', '=', $someDate)->get();
```

It returns an empty array, but i have the record with $someDate timestamp. How should i write a  right query?

Comment: What kind of database are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Result is correct, timestamps are `TIMESTAMP` fields:

```
`created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

So passing there a string `2014-07-01` will return expected rows only if time part is `00:00:00` (MySQL).

Instead use `DATE`:

```
$records = Records::where(DB::raw('DATE(created_at)'), $someDate)->get();
```

---

note Using Carbon won't help here in any way (unless, again, time part of the timestamp is `00:00:00`).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$records = Records::where('created_at', '>', \Carbon::parse('14 days ago'))->get();
```